# D3 ticked function does not find d.target.x

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I found a proper code snippet to add link:labels to my forced graph, which works fine. My problem is  that the `ticked()` function can´t find any d.target.x values. Those condition in the ticked function is responsible to rotate the label.

Beside the jfiddle, here is the original ticked function from the snippet.

Any idea?

```
function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function (d) {return d.source.x;})
        .attr("y1", function (d) {return d.source.y;})
        .attr("x2", function (d) {return d.target.x;})
        .attr("y2", function (d) {return d.target.y;});

    node
        .attr("transform", function (d) {return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";});

    edgepaths.attr('d', function (d) {
        return 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y;
    });

    edgelabels.attr('transform', function (d) {
        if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
            var bbox = this.getBBox();

            rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
            ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
            return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
        }
        else {
            return 'rotate(0)';
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<html>

<head>
    <title>Index jFiddle</title>
    <!-- favcon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="https://networkrepository.com/favicon.png">
    <!-- call external d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <!-- Load context menu -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.js"></script>

    <!-- load "font awesome" stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/39094309d6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px;
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    }

    .canvas {
        background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
    }

    .link {
        stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        stroke-width: 1px;
    }

    .node {
        stroke: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .icon {
        fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .node:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <svg id="svg"></svg>

    <!-- call app.js where the application is written -->
    <script>

        // define different variables
        var width = window.innerWidth
        height = window.innerHeight
        boolColor = true
        boolOpacity = true
        color = null
        nodes = null

        // define cavnas area to draw everything
        var svg = d3.select("svg")
            .attr("class", "canvas")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
                svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
            }))
            .append("g")

        svg.append('defs').append('marker')
            .attrs({
                'id': 'arrowhead',
                'viewBox': '-0 -5 10 10',
                'refX': 14,
                'refY': 0,
                'orient': 'auto',
                'markerWidth': 30,
                'markerHeight': 30,
                'xoverflow': 'visible'
            })
            .append('svg:path')
            .attr('d', 'M 0,-2 L 4 ,0 L 0,2')
            .attr('fill', 'black')
            .style('stroke', 'none');



        // Removes zoom on doubleclick listener
        d3.select("svg").on("dblclick.zoom", null)

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }).distance(100))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-400))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
            .force("attraceForce", d3.forceManyBody().strength(70));



        var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("opacity", 0);

        // load data from json file
        var data_nodes = [
            {
                "id": 00000,
                "type": "company",
                "name": "Test",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "Ideal" }
                ],
                "icon": "\uf1ad"
            },
            {
                "id": 00100,
                "type": "software",
                "name": "Jira",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "Jira" }
                ],
                "icon": "\uf7b1",
                "parent": 00000
            },
            {
                "id": 00200,
                "type": "software",
                "name": "Confluence",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "Confluence" }
                ],
                "icon": "\uf78d",
                "parent": 00000
            },
            {
                "id": 00300,
                "type": "software",
                "name": "IVIS",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "IVIS" }
                ],
                "icon": "\ue084",
                "parent": 00000
            },
            {
                "id": 00400,
                "type": "software",
                "name": "IPOS",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "IPOS" }
                ],
                "icon": "\ue084",
                "parent": 00000
            },
            {
                "id": 00500,
                "type": "software",
                "name": "IDAS",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "IDAS" }
                ],
                "icon": "\ue084",
                "parent": 00000
            },
            {
                "id": 99998,
                "type": "hardware",
                "name": "usv",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "usv" }
                ],
                "icon": "\uf5df",
                "parent": 00000
            },
            {
                "id": 99997,
                "type": "hardware",
                "name": "power-plug",
                "context": [
                    { "name": "power-plug" }
                ],
                "icon": "\uf1e6",
                "parent": 00000
            },
        ]

        var data_links = [

            { "source": 99998, "target": 00000, "type": "uses" },
            { "source": 99997, "target": 00000, "type": "uses" },
            { "source": 00100, "target": 00000, "type": "uses" },
            { "source": 00200, "target": 00000, "type": "uses" },
            { "source": 00300, "target": 00000, "type": "uses" },
            { "source": 00400, "target": 00000, "type": "uses" },
            { "source": 00500, "target": 00000, "type": "uses" },

        ]



        // create links which visualize relationships
        var links = svg.selectAll("line")
            .data(data_links)
            .enter()
            .append("line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke-width", 1)
            .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')

        links.append("title")
            .text(function (d) { return d.type; });

        edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
            .data(data_links)
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attrs({
                'class': 'edgepath',
                'fill-opacity': 0,
                'stroke-opacity': 0,
                'id': function (d, i) { return 'edgepath' + i }
            })
            .style("pointer-events", "none");

        edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel")
            .data(data_links)
            .enter()
            .append('text')
            .style("pointer-events", "none")
            .attrs({
                'class': 'edgelabel',
                'id': function (d, i) { return 'edgelabel' + i },
                'font-size': 10,
                'fill': 'black'
            });

        edgelabels.append('textPath')
            .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) { return '#edgepath' + i })
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("pointer-events", "none")
            .attr("startOffset", "50%")
            .text(function (d) { return d.type });

        var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data_nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", 30)
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("fill", initialColor)
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragStarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragEnded)
            )

        var icons = svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(data_nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("class", "icon")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
            .style("font-family", "FontAwesome")
            .style("font-size", "30px")
            .text(function (d) { return d.icon; })
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragStarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragEnded)
            )

        simulation.nodes(data_nodes).on("tick", ticked);

        simulation.force("link").links(data_links);


        function ticked() {
            // update link positions
            links
                .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

            // update node positions
            

            
            nodes
                .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
            

            // update icon positions
            icons
                .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x })
                .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y })

            edgepaths.attr('d', function (d) {
                return 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y;
            });

            edgelabels.attr('transform', function (d) {
                //console.log("d.target: " + d.target)
                //console.log("d.source: " + d.source)

                
                if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
                    var bbox = this.getBBox();
                    
                    rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
                    ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
                    return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
                }
                else {
                    return 'rotate(0)';
                }
                
            });

        }

        /*
            Set the color of each node in dependency of their d.name attribute.
        */
        function initialColor(d) {
            switch (d.name) {
                case "power-plug":
                    return "lightgreen"
                case "usv":
                    return "orange"
                default:
                    return "whitesmoke"
            }
        }

        /*
            dragStarted() / dragged() and dragEnded() controlling the drag behaviour of each
            object. In case all drag events are not desired, simple comment out the .call(d3.drag())
            execution during the object(node) creation
        */
        function dragStarted(d) {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
            d.fx = d.x;
            d.fy = d.y;
        }

        function dragged(d) {
            d.fx = d3.event.x;
            d.fy = d3.event.y;
        }

        function dragEnded(d) {
            if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
            d.fx = undefined;
            d.fy = undefined;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. Seems D3 supports only to have one .append("text") element. I removed the icon´s and the error was gone.